# Derivation of work done by external torque

Tags: electrostatics, work, conventions, torque, dipole

[image]

In this derivation, why isn't external torque the negative of torque of electric field and therefore Text = -PE sinø

Comment: I would suggest retyping derivation here, not just picture(latex commands).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Potential Energy of a Dipole in an External Field.**
external torque is caused by an external electric field, so it has positive sign, also angle θ is increasing in counterclockwise direction(as shown on illustration). For those two reasons, torque remains positive.